# JQuery DataTable: How to hide multple variable columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an array (colNumArray) which holds the indexes of the columns I wish to hide but I can't figure out a way to loop over this array and set the visibility of those indexes to false. Here is my code:

```
function runQuery(ProfileName)  //this uses bootstraps data tables plugin
        {
            var columnsArray = [];
            var toHideArray = [];
            var colNumArray = [];

                                   $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "sharedComponents.cfc",
                                        data: { method: "checkHeaders",
                                               default_sql_query_name: ProfileName
                                              },
                                        datatype: "json"

                                        }).done(function(returnresult) { 
                                            var filteredResult = returnresult;
                                            filteredResult = filteredResult.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
                                            filteredResult = filteredResult.trim(); 
                                            var headersArray = filteredResult.split(','); //headersArray holds each of the values in the needed headers table that will be used as headers in the data table

//                                                   for(i of headersArray) //For every column in the return result add that column to the headers table
//                                                        {
//                                                            alert(i); 
//                                                        }

                                           $.ajax({
                                                    type: "POST",
                                                    url: "sharedcomponents.cfc",
                                                    data: { method: "runSelectedQuery",
                                                            sql_query: btoa($('#textareaQuery').val())
                                                          },

                                                    datatype: "json",
                                                    success: function(data) {
                                                              $.each(data.COLUMNS, function(index, item) {  //index is the column array position, item is the value of the column array at [index] position
                                                            columnsArray.push(item);
                                                            });
                                                        for(i of columnsArray) 
                                                        {
                                                            if(headersArray.includes(i)){
                                                                toHideArray.push(i);
                                                            } 
                                                        }                                                       
                                                        $.each(data.COLUMNS, function(index, item) {  //index is the column array position, item is the value of the column array at [index] position
                                                            if(toHideArray.includes(item)){
                                                                colNumArray.push(index);
                                                            }
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                }).done(function(returnresult) {
                                                   var tableLogData = $('#TripLogTable').DataTable({
                                                            columnDefs: [
                                                                { targets: '-all', visible: true}/*,
                                                                { targets: [colNumArray[0], colNumArray[1]], visible: false } */
                                                            ]
                                                        });
                                                    tableLogData.clear();


                                                        console.log(colNumArray[0], colNumArray[4]);
                                                        console.log([colNumArray[0], colNumArray[1]]);

                                                    returnresult['DATA'].forEach( function (row) {
                                                    const rowData = {};
                                                    for (let i in row) {
                                                        rowData[i] = row[i];
                                                    }
                                                    tableLogData.row.add(rowData).draw( false );
                                                    })

                                                });
                            });
                            }
```

I thought you might like to see the big picture, but the problem more specifically is right here:

```
var tableLogData = $('#TripLogTable').DataTable({
                    columnDefs: [
                    { targets: '-all', visible: true},
                    { targets: [colNumArray[0], colNumArray[1]], visible: false } 
                                                            ]
                                                        });
```

As you can see, I do know how to set the visibility of a set number of indexes to false, but how could I set the visibility to false for each number inside the colNumArray array?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I did not know you could do this outside of columnDefs. Below the columnDefs brackets and under tableLogData.clear(); this is what I did:

```
 for(i of colNumArray){
     tableLogData.column(i).visible(false); 
 }
```

Where as you can see above tableLogData was the variable name for the datatable.